# Solve for $f(3)$ given the equation: $5f(x) - 2(1/x) = x^2$

Tags: functions

> Let $f$ solve the equation
>      $$5f(x) - 2(1/x) = x^2.$$
>   What is $f(3)$?

I'm assuming that I need to solve for $f$ but how do I do that?

Comment: It appears that $f$ is explicitly expressed.

Comment: with the expression of lab bhattarcharjee the problem is more interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$5f(3) - 2(1/3) = 3^2$$ so $f(3)=\frac{3^2+\frac{2}{3}}{5}$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Assuming $$5f(x)-2f\left(1/x\right)=x^2$$

Set $x=y, \dfrac1y$

and solve the two simultaneous equations for $f(y), f\left(1/y\right)$

Comment: but why?  is it needed?

Comment: @RaziehNoori, $1/x$ inspires the thought of $f(1/x)$